# Saving data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The response for an api call is like so:

```
//Calling the api
  useEffect(() => {
    runFunction(params, someMoreParams);
  });


  async function setDeliveryOptions(cartItems, checkoutState) {
    const response = await authFetch({
      url: `apiURL`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(orderBody),
    });

    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);

    const deliveries = jsonResponse.deliveries.map(
      (items) => items.scheduleOptions,
    );

    
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
    
    //RESPONSE:

    deliveries: Array(1). 
    0:  items: (2) [{…}, {…}]
        options: 0:   //THIS IS THE DATA  I WANT
                      end: "2022-09-01T15:15:00Z"
                      price:55
                      price_ex_vat: 44
                      start: "2022-09-01T15:15:00Z"
                      type: "POSTAL"
                      [[Prototype]]: Object
        supplier: "supplier"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    length: 1
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)


    const data = jsonResponse.options.map(
      (items) => items.options,
    );

    // trying to save data:
   

    const type = data.map((items) => items);
    const start = data[0].map((items) => items.start);
    const end = data[0].map((items) => items.end);
    const price = data[0].map((items) => items.price);

    console.log('deliveries', data);
    console.log('type', type);
    console.log('start', start);
    console.log('end', end);
    console.log('price', price);
  }
```

how do i get the data and save it to a variable. this is run on react, and is called when website is rendered. This code saves the data to the variables but i get a react error stating that values are undefined. maybe it is a react thing?

thanks for any help

Comment: please add *all* **relevant** code.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you got?

Comment: So the "response" key is part of the response?  And you have a variable called `response` which holds this response?  `data = response.response[0][0].data`

Comment: That is not a valid object structure. Did you miss some `{` or `[` ?

Comment: just added new detailt @Thomas

Comment: Saving to what? If you want to save to a file, Data serialization is very reliable solution.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha OP doesn't know how to read the data structure in the console and therefore access its values.

Comment: @bladerunner69 as sinan yaman already mentioned, `{}` and `[]` are also relevant. going by what you posted I'd say `data = jsonResponse.deliveries[0].options`